# ASP MVC Core, Telerik Grid not refreshing after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik

I am trying to use an html select to send, via an ajax call, the selected count value to the controller to reload a Telerik Kendo grid with the amount of database rows in the count.

I think this issue is do to some error that I have with my Ajax call and the Controller.  I default the grid count to 50 on load with the following in _Layout.cshtml.

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="LocalOptions" 
        asp-action="KendoTest" asp-route-count="50">KendoTest</a>
</li>
```

Issue: the grid loads with the 50 rows.  Then, when I select from the drop down ie: 500, the ajax function calls the controller action and the parameter count and ViewData["SelectedOption"] are set to 500.  Then in the Views first Razor @{ } code block, the database call fires and repopulates the list CurrOptionData with the new list of data.

The problem is that the Kendo grid never reloads with the new rows, it stays at the initial 50.  I can type 500 at the end of the URL in the browser and then the grid refreshes with the correct count of rows.

Note: I have tried using `$("#dataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();` and `$("#dataGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();` in the ajax success: but no change.

*********  LocalOptionsController.cs *********

```
 public IActionResult KendoTest(int count)
 {
     ViewData["Selected`your text`Option"] = count;
     return View();
 }
```

************ VIEW ************

This code block calls GetCurrOptionsByCount with the passed in count
from ViewData[ ] and populates the list of object call CurrOptionData

```
 @{
List<CurrOption>? CurrOptionData;
int countToDisplay = 50;
int loadedRows = 50;

countToDisplay = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["SelectedOption"]);
loadedRows = countToDisplay;

CurrOptionData = await _db.GetCurrOptionsByCount(countToDisplay);

 }

<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 15px; text-align: center;">
            Select Current Options To Display:
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
        <select name="options" id="OptionCount" style="height: 25px;">
                <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
                <option value="500">500</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="10000">10000</option>
                <option value="100000">100000</option>
                <option value="200000">200000</option>
                <option value="300000">300000</option>
                <option value="400000">400000</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My Kendo grid defined in Razor code.

```
@(

Html.Kendo().Grid(CurrOptionData)
     .Name("dataGrid")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("ID").Width(105);
    columns.Bound(p => p.USID).Title("USID").Width(120);
    columns.Bound(p => p.SellID).Title("SellID").Width(130);
    columns.Bound(p => p.OptionID).Title("OptionID").Width(170);
     })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    )
    )
}

<script>
```

Ajax call to call the Action KendoTest to reload and refresh with the selected count from
my dropdown.

```
document.getElementById('OptionCount').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = this.value;       

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("KendoTest", "LocalOptions")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { count: selectedValue }, 
        success: function () {

            $("#dataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            $("#dataGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
        
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error occurred during the AJAX call.');
        }
    });

});  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard this post, I have solved this issue by calling

```
window.location.href = '/Controller/view?count=' + param
```

The problem wasn't that my Ajax call was failing to call the action.  The issue was that I was not refreshing the page.

Thanks